# How to get the value from a key directly?

Tags: json, vb.net

I am new to VB and Json. Here is the code of obtaining the value of the key `ID`. Can I get it directly instead using a loop?

```
data_Obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(data_result)

For Each obj In data_Obj
    If obj.Key.Equals("ID") Then
        str_id = obj.Value
    End If
Next
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to have a loop. One of the main reasons to have a Dictionary is the very fast access to its elements. You could use [TryGetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
data_Obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(data_result)
Dim str_id as String
if data_Obj.TryGetValue("ID", str_id) Then
    ' SUCCESS 
else
    ' FAILURE
end if
```

This is safest method because it doesn't trigger an exception in case your key doesn't exist in the returned dictionary.

Comment: How to use TryGetValue to get a nested value?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question. In this context I assumed the value to be a string. If not then you should explain what is it. However if the value is another Dictionary, nothing prevents you to call again TryGetValue on the nested dictionary.

Comment: I mean using TryGetValue inside TryGetValue  without creating variables for intermediate steps.

Comment: The variable is used as a ByRef parameter so that the result can be assigned whilst still giving the success/failure of the method. You can decline to give one and use `Nothing`, but then you'll be accessing the dictionary twice which is more expensive, and in that case you could use `If data_Obj.ContainsKey("ID") Then`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
data_Obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(data_result)

str_id = data_Obj.item("ID")
```

as if data_Obj is a normal Dictionary